# Puppeteer downloads blank PDF instead of the one expected, with content

Tags: download, puppeteer

I have to download a pdf, but it requires first to collect cookies, by visiting the page which hosts the PDF link.
I click the link but a blanc PDF is downloaded with same pages number as the expected one.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        dumpio: true,
        headless: false,
        devtools: true,// I want to see what's going on
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));

    await page.goto(url_cookie, { waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'load'] });
    page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './', });
    page.once('response', async (response) => {
        if (response.url() !== url_pdf) return;
        console.log('resp', response.url());
    });
    const css = 'a[href="' + url + '"]';
    await page.waitForSelector(css)

    const eval = async css => {
        const a = document.querySelector(css);
        console.log(a)
        return fetch(a.href, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        }).then(r => r.text())
    };
    const txt = await page.evaluate(eval, [css]);

    fs.writeFileSync('./test.pdf', txt,)
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```